# How do I use BlueCove to use Bluetooth on a MacBook with Java?

Tags: java, macos, bluetooth, bluecove

I would like to implement an Java application that uses Bluetooth on my MacBook Air laptop. I try to use the Java bluetooth library [BlueCove](http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/).

I tried to implement the first example [DeviceDiscovery](http://www.bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/overview-summary.html#DeviceDiscovery) but it throws an `BluetoothStateException` with the message: `BlueCove library bluecove not available`. I have added `bluecove-2.1.0.jar` to my Build Path in Eclipse.

What is the problem? How can I use BlueCove with my MacBook Air?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892738/mac-os-and-java-bluetooth/41319931#41319931

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BlueCove requires the 32-bit JVM to run.  Adding the `-d32` argument to `java` to force the 32-bit JVM will fix the problem.  You can do this in Eclipse under VM Arguments for the launch configuration.

Comment: It's worth noting that this problem will occur under Windows as well.  The `-d32` trick works there, too.

Comment: Eclipse says : This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM