# Bluetooth APIs for Java SE

Tags: java, bluetooth

I have a Java ME application in my mobile (Client code). I need to write Java SE code (Server-side) so that client-server connection is established through bluetooth. Gonna use obex bluetooth as my need is to transfer a text file from mobile to laptop.

So, for pc side Java SE bluetooth coding, i tried with Bluecove.2.1.1.jar for jsr-82 implementation. But my laptop is win 7 64 bit os and hence i ended up with the error : "bluecove_x64.dll is missing". So, now moving on to AvetanaBluetooth.jar library.

I have downloaded from the Avetana site as a 14-days trial pack. Can anyone please help me on how to implement it? Like, any sample codes or tutorial/ procedure/instructions will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BlueCove should be sufficient for your server application, but it requires the 32-bit JVM to run. Adding the `-d32` argument to `java` to force the 32-bit JVM will fix the problem. You can do in Eclipse this under VM Arguments for the launch configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I think [pwc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/511287/pwc) already answered to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938809/how-do-i-use-bluecove-to-use-bluetooth-on-a-macbook-with-java)

So Bluecove is good unless you want to spend some money on the other library :)