# Mac OS and Java bluetooth

Tags: java, macos, bluetooth

After searching for hours, I decided to ask this question here.
For JSR-82 (bluetooth), there is an implementation called bluecove. However, the Mac OS version relies on a 32 bit VM (the last time the library was updated was back in 2008). The problem is that newer JDK versions for the Mac do not support 32 bit anymore (the -d32 argument just gives me an error).

So is there a possibility to get a 32 bit JVM for Mac OS? Or are there other implementations for bluetooth that support 64 bit VMs?

Comment: Hi Brother, got any solution? I am finding the same :D . Is that will be better if I pass the message to the Mac using other lang than java after that pass that message through a local socket connection ? I thought this as a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

You can use newest version(2.1.2) of Bluecove. It is not officially announced by Bluecove team but It has native OSX 64 bit support. I found this version at [Bluecove issue page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/bluecove/issues/134). Please look under Comment #21. If you want you can download it [here](http://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-attachments/bluecove/issue-134/comment-21/bluecove-2.1.2.jar).

Comment: long shot, but the link doesn't work anymore. anyone has found an alternative link to 2.1.2 that works on a mac?