# Native library bluecove not available on Mac

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bluetooth, bluecove

I downloaded bluecove-2.1.0.jar and added it as an external JAR on my Eclipse project. I am following this tutorial for using Bluetooth with Android: http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/android-java-bluetooth/

When I run the program intended for my laptop to act as a server, I get an error stating 'Native library bluecove not available'. I made sure bluetooth was enabled by typing 'bluetooth' in Spotlight (which took me to Bluetooth File Exchange and allowed me to select a file to send).

I saw another Stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938809/how-do-i-use-bluecove-to-use-bluetooth-on-a-macbook-with-java) stating that BlueCove requires 32-bit JVM to run so I added the -d32 argument under VM arguments in the run configuration. When I ran it, I got another error stating

"Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version."

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenJDK may work as Mike suggested but its installation process was rather involved. I found a workaround by installing an earlier version of Eclipse that supported 32-bit OS X versions and setting -d32 in the VM arguments there worked without issues. Be sure to keep the earlier version of Eclipse in a separate folder so it doesn't overwrite your recent version.

I installed the 32-bit version of Eclipse Kepler from here: https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Kepler/SR2

Of course, Bluecove had some other issues with IOBluetooth device not found (since Apple removed that since OS X 10.8 I believe), for which you can check here for a possible [solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!msg/bluecove-users/7jWv1V1GC-4/6pShd9vssAEJ).

Answer (score 1):

Try using OpenJDK rather than the Oracle JDK. This supports the -d32 arguments so it ought to work for you.